# How do you make cmd have options for the user, that can skip or go back?

Tags: windows, cmd, command

I have playing around with CMD right, my problem is that I need to skip (or make an option) or the user to skip the set commands.
For my English how-to project, I want to know how I skip/direct to an answer or command.

Here are my commands so far.

```
  @echo off

  color 0a

  echo okay time for a pop up? yes or no?

  timeout 5

  echo MSGBOX "Message Text!",48,"Title Text!" > %temp%\TEMPmessage.vbs

  call %temp%\TEMPmessage.vbs

  del %temp%\TEMPmessage.vbs /f /q

  pause

  echo Now do cls for clearing cmd so you have a clean plate to work on.

  echo Now you are done! Follow this link for more commands...

  echo Here is the link 

  timeout 5

  color 0c

  cls

  echo (My link)
```

That's how is set now. What I want to find out is: How do you skip to the link?
Like...

Do you want a pop up? Yes or no?
(user selects no)

### Then skips to the link.

Do you want a pop up? Yes or no?
(user selects yes) 
And then the temp vbs window pops up.

Other things that might be important: Windows 7, Hp, I am a beginner, so this is just a hobby.
That's it. Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `choice`:

```
choice /C YN /M "Do you want a popup?"
if %errorlevel%==1 goto YES
if %errorlevel%==2 goto NO
:YES
echo you choosed YES
goto contiue
:NO
echo you choosed NO
goto continue
:continue
REM more code here
```

You can use `set /p`

```
:input
set /p "x=Do you want a popup?"
if /i "%x%"="Y" goto YES
if /i "%x%"="N" goto NO
echo wrong input
goto input
:YES
echo you choosed YES
goto contiue
:NO
echo you choosed NO
goto continue
:continue
REM more code here
```

`choice` will only accept one of the given letters (only one letter possible, no ENTER needed), while `set` will accept any input. So in your case, I'd prefer `choice`.

Comment: Thanks for the help :D Now This is what I am figuring out how to make Y open the pop up (Like goto Y. When user says Yes) and N skips and goto :N

Comment: I edited my answer. Note: this is neither the best nor the most elegant solution but the "best understandable"  for beginners (and with a minimum chance for any programmatical traps)